# Share value between variables is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm implementing a search box by Angular 5. I have a component for the search box and another component for search result. When I pass the value through input element to the variable `'v'` in search.component.html, It updates the 'v' in `search-result.component.ts`, so **{{v}}** in html shows the value that I entered.

To filter the array, I am taking `'v'` to `'term'` and do the filter function. But, after loading the page, It is only showing the **{{v}}** value and Not showing the **{{term}}** and **{{filterarray}}**

What is the wrong here?

`search.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { error } from 'util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

  v: string;

  @Output() valueEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(){}

  sendValue(){
    this.valueEvent.emit(this.v)
  }

  ngOnInit()
  }
}
```

`saerch.component.html:`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="v"><button (click)="sendValue()">Search</button>
```

saerch-result.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-result',
  templateUrl: './search-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-result.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultComponent{

 v: string;

 term: string = this.v;

 array: any[]=[{'id':1,'name':'Jones'},{'id':2,'name':'Duke'},{'id':3,'name':'Frank'},{'id':4,'name':'Jonas'}];
  filterarray: any[];

  constructor(){

    this.filterarray=this.array.filter(f => f.name.includes(this.term)).map(searchname=>searchname.name);

  }

   receiveValue($event){
    this.v = $event
    }
}
```

`search-result.component.html:`

```
<app-search (valueEvent)="receiveValue($event)"></app-search>
<p>{{v}}</p>
<p>{{term}}</p>
<p>{{filterarray}}</p>
```

Comment: term it's only equal to v at first the component and filterarray too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this line:

`this.filterarray=this.array.filter(f => f.name.includes(this.term)).map(searchname=>searchname.name);`

To inside:

```
receiveValue($event){
   this.v = $event
}
```

So something like this:

```
receiveValue($event){
       this.v = $event
       this.filterarray=this.array.filter(f => f.name.includes(this.term)).map(searchname=>searchname.name);
    }
```

That way every time the user hits search button the array will be updated.

Comment: My pleasure Prasad, can you please accept my answer it would be much appreciated. I have also done a stackblitz here for you of the working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqm3ru

Comment: Done!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move filter and also assign value to inside **receiveValue** method

like this,

```
 v: string;

  term: string;

  array: any[] = [{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'Jones' }, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Duke' }, { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Frank' }, { 'id': 4, 'name': 'Jonas' }];
  filterarray: any[];

  constructor() { }

  receiveValue(event) {
    this.v = event;
    this.term = this.v;
    this.filterarray = this.array.filter(f => f.name.includes(this.term)).map(searchname => searchname.name);

  }
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n91wup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo